# Selecting English in the Whatsapp API link

Tags: whatsapp

I hope this is a do-able thing.. I have my website where I link certain services to have us contact via Whatsapp using the link below:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=97112345678&text=Hi+there%2C++I+would+like+you+to+book+for+ABC&app_absent=0

PS - I wrote a random phone number 97112345678 above. This can by any phone number with whatsapp.

On the desktop version of my site, this page opens up in Arabic for now since I am accessing this in UAE. Can I append something in the URL itself to land the page in English always? I tried "lang=en" as a guess but did not work.

[link below showing the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPhPk.png)

Comment: Appending `&lang=de` to the end of the URL seems to work fine for me.

Comment: :( you are right, I was missing the & -> stupid me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The language setting for your WhatsApp needs to be done on your mobile device. Follow the steps below to change your language. (Note that if you don't see the option below, it might not be supported in your country.)

1. Open WhatsApp.
2. Tap More options > Settings > Chats > App Language.
3. Select the language that you want (English).

Comment: Hello Ezani, thanks. But this is for desktop. When a user accesses this link, the page gives instructions on how to proceed towards Whatsapp Web and also the information of the whatsapp-account it links to. All this info is in Arabic (country dependent for now). So I am wondering of the language can be statically set in the link itself.